# Multiple Image View in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I worked with Android studio, 
when I use more than one image view in a one interface form the spacing between the images is too big such that when the app is run, an empty form is appears between the forms containing the image view.

Any help please?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots or the layout file code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if it is what you are looking for but remember that in Xml file you can set layout margins:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

and there are more options available. Check this [Margin Layout Params](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html).
If you're using Relative Layout check this [Relative Layout Params](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).